# What does "A small town girl with big city dreams" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms, lyrics

> A small town girl with big city dreams

What does a "small town girl" mean? Does it mean she is *small* in stature or short?  And what does "big city dreams" mean?  Does it mean the dreams are *big* in some way?

Can you please explain this sentence to me? I can't understand it.

Comment: Obligatory Journey reference: https://youtu.be/KCy7lLQwToI (first line at about 0:20)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Why was google not good enough for this? To post a question on this site you must include prior research. Take the [Tour] and see [ask] for more.

Answer (score 6):

It means two things:

1. She's from a small town. Think of barns, fields, goats, and a handful of people wearing over-alls who seem to be proud of their drawls. The most exciting thing that happens in a typical week might be when farmer John's tractor breaks down. (This is a terrible and inaccurate characterization, but it's the kind of thought that the phrase is essentially intending to invoke.)
2. She has aspirations involving the glitz and glamour of things that are more often found in big cities. Think of places like Carnegie Hall and Universal Studios, and people like George Clooney and Julia Roberts. Money, fame, luxury, etc.

The phrase "small town girl" may also imply that she's kind of innocent and naive and maybe doesn't have a lot of experience with the larger world out there. If she took the midnight train going anywhere, then she's bored out of her mind and can't stand it anymore.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer.... Perhaps it's worth mentioning that "small town boy / girl"  is a very typical expression from north America, and it *can* be used in a derogative sense.

Comment: Well, *city girl* can be used in a derogatory sense too. Probably most descriptions can be used "in a derogatory sense." And there's the continent *North America*, but I'm not sure what "north America" is supposed to refer to.